# Building Insight Debugger on Fedora 25 opncls error

Tags: fedora

I'm trying to manually install insight on Fedora 25. Gdb version is 7.12-29.fc25. The configure run correctly, yet the make errors as shown. Upon googling the issues it seemed to have been corrected on [git](https://github.com/open-power/p8-pore-binutils/issues/2), however I'm still experiencing the issue.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

From my make:

```
in file included from /home/murray/local/src/insight-6.8-1/bfd/opncls.c:26:0:
/home/murray/local/src/insight-6.8-1/bfd/opncls.c: In function 'bfd_fopen':
./bfd.h:586:65: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
 #define bfd_set_cacheable(abfd,bool) (((abfd)->cacheable = bool), TRUE)
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/home/murray/local/src/insight-6.8-1/bfd/opncls.c:235:5: note: in expansion of macro 'bfd_set_cacheable'
     bfd_set_cacheable (nbfd, TRUE);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:1071: recipe for target 'opncls.lo' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

6.8.1 is terribly outdated. Either use the insight package provided by Fedora or use a git snapshot from git://sourceware.org/git/insight.git. There are some instructions in the README file (https://sourceware.org/git/?p=insight.git;a=blob;f=README).